# ¿Como utilizar un controlador para varios formularios en laravel?

Tags: laravel

Tengo un proyecto en laravel 6, y necesito utilizar un mismo controlador para varios formularios, es decir varias rutas en el mismo controlador.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por favor, comparte tu código con formato de texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tendrías que declarar tus propias funciones con nombres distintos y al momento de crear tus rutas deberás poner una ruta por cada una de las acciones.

**Rutas:**

```
Route::get('/empleados', 'controller@verListaDeEmpleados');
Route::get('/empleados/{id_empleado}', 'controller@verEmpleado');
Route::get('/empleados/create', 'controller@verAgregarEmpleado');
Route::post('/empleados', 'controller@agregarEmpleado');
Route::get('/empleados/{id_empleado}/edit', 'controller@verModificarEmpleado');
Route::patch('/empleados/{id_empleado}', 'controller@modificarEmpleado');
Route::delete('/empleados/{id_empleado}', 'controller@eliminarEmpleado');
```

**Controlador:**

```
public function verListaDeEmpleados()
{
    //CÓDIGO PARA VER LISTA DE EMPLEADOS
}
public function verEmpleado($id)
{
    //CÓDIGO PARA VER INFORMACION DE 1 EMPLEADO MEDIANTE SU ID
}
public function verAgregarEmpleado()
{
    //CÓDIGO PARA VER FORMULARIO DE CREACION DE EMPLEADO
}

public function agregarEmpleado(Request $request)
{
    //CÓDIGO PARA CREAR EMPLEADO
}
public function verModificarEmpleado($id)
{
    //CÓDIGO PARA VER FORMULARIO DE MODIFICAR DE EMPLEADO
}
public function modificarEmpleado(Request $request, $id){
    //CÓDIGO PARA MODIFICAR EMPLEADO
}
public function eliminarEmpleado($id){
    //CÓDIGO PARA ELIMINAR EMPLEADO
}
```

De igual manera le puedes echar un ojo a la [documentación oficial de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers) sobre los controladores en donde explican como funcionan los controladores de tipo recurso para que te des una idea del funcionamiento de estos.